# How to find optimal line on y axis using a divide and conquer algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

If I am given a group of numbers that are positions on the y axis how do I find the position on the y axis that is has the shortest total difference in respect to the group of numbers. For example, if you are give the numbers 1 8 3 6 2 7 it should return the number 5 because it has the smallest total difference at 15. It has to be a divide and conquer approach. I do not need code I need an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your example: `1 8 3 6 2 7`.  I'm assuming we're looking for an integer answer.

The answer has to be between the smallest and the largest number.  0 has a larger sum of differences than 1.  8 has a smaller sum of differences than 9.

With your example, the end bounds are 1 and 8.  Add them together and integer divide by 2.  This gives us 4.  Or, as an alternative, add all the numbers together and divide by the number count.  With your example the sum is 27.  Integer dividing by 6 yields 4.

The sum of the differences for 4 is 15.  First, let's back up and see if the answer is smaller.

The sum of the differences for 3 is 15.  So, let's back up again.

The sum of the differences for 2 is 17.  We don't have to go any further in this direction.  So, going the other direction from 4.

The sum of the differences for 5 is 15.  So, let's move forward.

The sum of the differences for 6 is 15.  Again, let's move forward.

The sum of the differences for 7 is 17.

So, the final answer is 3, 4, 5, or 6.  I'm not sure how you choose one to be the correct answer.

In this case, we could have just checked all the numbers between 1 and 8, inclusive.  But when the integers get to be larger, like 1,000, this divide and conquer method is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the numbers.  You can use a divide and conquer algorithm for that.

Then the optimal line is at the number in the middle, or anywhere between the two middle numbers if there are an even number of them.

Notice that in your example, 3, 4, 5, and 6 *all* have a total difference of 15.

Why this works:

If you have `n` numbers above your line and `m` numbers below your line, and you move your line by 'x', then the change in the total difference is `m*x - n*x`.  So if your line has more numbers above, then you should move it up.  If it has more numbers below, then you should move it down.  When it has the same number above and below, then it's optimal.